# Why new Date() function not working in safari .?

Tags: javascript, extjs

By using bellow code I am calculating difference between 2 date which are format in string like *2017-12-19 17:19:35* 
I did code as bellow, working in google chrome but not in safari.

```
    var lastReportingTime = r.get('updatedate'); // 2017-12-19 17:19:35
    var serverCurrentTime = r.get('currtime'); //2018-02-09 03:52:42

    var diff = new Date(serverCurrentTime) - new Date(lastReportingTime);
    diff /= 60000; //diff converted in minutes.

    console.log('diff=',diff);
   // for chrome output is diff= 4445024000
   // for safari output is diff= NaN
```

In chrome `diff` returning result in minutes but same code in safari browser returns `NaN`

have you any solution for this?

Comment: Use `new Date().valueOf()`, it's supported in both Safari and Chrome

Comment: If you use `valueOf()` then `getDate()` and `setDate()` functions will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of the date constructor varies across different browsers. Certain strings that parse correctly in Chrome may not parse correctly in Safari. Instead of using `new Date()`, use `Ext.Date.parse(theDateString, theExpectedFormat)`. [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-parse).

Comment: Sorry this solution is not working for me.
ReferenceError: Ext is not defined

Comment: The question is tagged as `extjs`, so the solution uses it. If you're not using Ext, then yeah this isn't for you.

Comment: Okay, but it was not mentioned anywhere in the question so I didn't know it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```js
   // var lastReportingTime = r.get('updatedate'); // 2017-12-19 17:19:35
   // var serverCurrentTime = r.get('currtime'); //2018-02-09 03:52:42

     var lastReportingTime = "2017-12-19 17:19:35"
     var serverCurrentTime = "2018-02-09 03:52:42"
  
    var diff = new Date(serverCurrentTime.replace(/-/g, "/")) - new Date(lastReportingTime.replace(/-/g, "/"));
    diff /= 60000; //diff converted in minutes.

    console.log('diff=',diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().valueOf()` to get the milliseconds and then subtract.

Reference and support table:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, It's easy to verify that `new Date() - new Date()` returns `0` in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

Use Date.getTime() for mathematical operations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: That isn't the problem, the issue is that the date doesn't parse.